# How to evaluate Tensorflow Object Detection API on only one particular class?

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, object-detection-api, faster-rcnn

I have trained an object detection model from Tensorflow Object Detection API `faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco` on about 10 classes. When I run the `model_main.py` file to evaluate the model, it seems to only give the mean Average Precision (AP) and Average Recall (AR) of all the 10 classes, like below:

```
Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.331
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50      | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.479
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.75      | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.395
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100 ] = 0.600
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=medium | maxDets=100 ] = 0.407
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100 ] = 0.333
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=  1 ] = 0.358
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets= 10 ] = 0.544
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.548
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100 ] = 0.600
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=medium | maxDets=100 ] = 0.545
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100 ] = 0.551
```

However, if I want to just evaluate the performance on 1 particular class, instead of all 30 detected classes, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code to filter objects of interest, after the detection -

---

```
objectOfInterest = 1  # Interested object class number as per label file 
box = np.asarray(boxes)
cls = np.asarray(classes).astype(np.int32)
scr = np.asarray(scores)
bl = (cls == objectOfInterest) 
classes = np.extract(boolar,cls)
scores = np.extract(boolar,scr)
boxes = np.extract(boolar,box)
```

---

Comment: I mean evaluating, not displaying. I think it's in the `model_main.py` or `model_lib.py` but I don't know how to modify them to evaluate on only 1 class

Comment: For changes in the number of classes in the model detection, you need to create the dataset with same number of classes and train the model accordingly. Check out this link for more information on how to create your own dataset - https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/using_your_own_dataset.md

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never - From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67994364/is-there-a-convenient-way-to-get-class-specific-average-precision-scores-for-a-t/68010356#68010356) post

**1. Use a different evaluation configuration**

Simply change the `metrics_set` value in the `*.config` file for your model to `"pascal_voc_detection_metrics"`.

The TensorFlow Object Detection API supports a variety of evaluation metrics, detailed in the documentation [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/evaluation_protocols.md). The PASCAL VOC 2010 detection metric gives AP scores for each class.

**2. Edit the `cocoeval.py` file in your pycocotools package**

This method involves pasting 8 lines of code into the `cocoeval.py` file. It is well explained and documented in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56247323/coco-api-evaluation-for-subset-of-classes) post.