# Is there a convenient way to get class-specific Average Precision scores for a TensorFlow Object Detection model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

The TensorFlow Object Detection API has a very convenient way to get performance metrics for trained models (described in their tutorial [here](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html#evaluating-the-model-optional)). Unfortunately, the Average Precision scores for each class are not provided.

Does anyone know of a convenient way to get class-specific AP scores for TensorFlow Object Detection models without having to write your own script to do it?

The [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59227059/how-to-evaluate-tensorflow-object-detection-api-on-only-one-particular-class) was asked in 2019 but was not answered.

Thanks!

Comment: No, this makes no sense, you can get AP per class, mAP is for all classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more searching, I found a couple solutions.

**1. Use a different evaluation configuration**

Simply change the `metrics_set` value in the `*.config` file for your model to `"pascal_voc_detection_metrics"`.

The TensorFlow Object Detection API supports a variety of evaluation metrics, detailed in the documentation [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/evaluation_protocols.md). The PASCAL VOC 2010 detection metric gives AP scores for each class.

**2. Edit the `cocoeval.py` file in your pycocotools package**

This method involves pasting 8 lines of code into the `cocoeval.py` file. It is well explained and documented in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56247323/coco-api-evaluation-for-subset-of-classes) post.