# COCO API evaluation for subsets of key points classes

Tags: python, pose-estimation, mscoco, pycocotools

I'm using the python coco API to run evaluation for Key points estimation. I have two files, a ground truth json, and a results json.

My goal is to evaluate KP estimation performance for ALL KP classes.

For example, for category 'person', I want something like this:

```
kp_category : 0 : 0.410733757610904   # "nose" AP
kp_category : 1 : 0.20226150054237374 # "right_eye" AP
```

However, the results are averaged across all key point classes.

The only thing that I found that might help is this SO question: [COCO API evaluation for subset of classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56247323/coco-api-evaluation-for-subset-of-classes). But the problem is that the suggested solution is good for outputting evaluation of different object categories and not their key points.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I have same question. Did you find a solution? Thanks.